# Double parentheses with three arguments, mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If I assign something like this to variable Res:

```
Res=Solve[6-5x+x^2==0];
```

What will do the following line?

```
Res[[1,1,2]]
```

or

```
Res[[2,1,2]]
```

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark
The result of Res is `{{x -> 2}, {x -> 3}}`, `Res[[1,1,2]] `returns 2, and `Res[[2,1,2]]` returns 3.

Comment: Another way to use Solve results would be to do   Res = x/. Solve[6-5x+x^2==0,x];  Res[[1]] and Res[[-1]] would give you the two solutions without having to figure out the structure of Rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's examine the `FullForm` of `Res` to see what `Res[[1,1,2]]` means:

```
In[1]:= Res = Solve[6 - 5 x + x^2 == 0]
Out[1]= {{x -> 2}, {x -> 3}}

In[2]:= FullForm[Res]                                                                               
Out[2]= List[List[Rule[x, 2]], List[Rule[x, 3]]]
```

Hence:

```
Res[[1]]     = List[Rule[x,2]]
Res[[1,1]]   = Rule[x,2]
Res[[1,1,2]] = 2
```